# Why can't I connect to my Linux bluetooth serial port?

Tags: android, serial-port, bluetooth, bluez

I have a USB bluetooth dongle on a Linux 3.12.5 ARM system.  I've been attempting to make a bluetooth serial connection from my android phone to the USB dongle on Linux.  I've referenced [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux) among other sources in my attempts.  Any suggestions would be great.

I have been able to make it pairable via:

```
bluetooth-agent 0000 &
```

And then pairing via from my phone.  Then, I create a serial port on the device via:

```
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/rfcomm0 c 216 0
sudo sdptool add --channel=22 SP
sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm 22
```

Then, from my phone, I use BlueTerm to attempt to connect to the serial port.  However, it loses connection immediately.  On the Linux side, the following appears in the terminal:

```
Waiting for connection on channel 22
Authorizing request for /org/bluez/317/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_00_46
```

It doesn't seem to be kicking the phone off the connection, so what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

The steps bellow worked for me:

Firstly you have to pair the devices. Pairing is relatively easy.
I will call client (who starts talking) and server (who replies)

You have to setup the server before:
Server side (as root):

```
sdptool add --channel=3 SP
mknod -m 666 /dev/rfcomm0 c 216 0
rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 3 /sbin/agetty rfcomm0 115200 linux
```

Client side(as root):

```
sdptool add --channel=3 SP
rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 [SERVER_ADDR] 3
```

Now to open a serial terminal on the client:

```
screen /dev/rfcomm0 115200
```

Comments:

When you call the last command `rfcomm connect`... in the client, a device `/dev/rfcomm0` will be created and associated to the server `/dev/recomm0`. This represents the serial link between both

The last server command: `rfcomm watch`.... will 'listen' for incoming connections. In connection lost, the command will restart a new 'listen' state.