# Bluetooth Dongle Connection refused .

Tags: debian, hardware, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth dongle (something that costs around $2) from which I want to send serial data to my android phone.

i have installed :

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez-utils blueman
```

on Scanning , I found my android device (i guess that means the dongle is working)

```
hcitool scan
```

after that I ran this:

```
sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I have edited this file : `/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf`

to this:

```
rfcomm1 {
    bind yes;
    device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
    channel 1;
    comment "Connection to Bluetooth serial module";
}
```

but on running

`sudo rfcomm connect 1` , I am getting '`Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused`'

What is the problem ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=125922

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/problem-using-bluetooth-mobile-as-modem-rfcomm-connection-refused-463292/

Answer (score 3):

> I seem to have gotten this working now. `Bluetooth` seems a bit finicky.
>   I'm recapping my steps in full in case someone else finds it useful
>   (though its pretty much what I tried initially). This is for Android
>   JB (4.2.2) on a Nexus 4 and Arch Linux 3.6.7-1, with bluez 4.101 on
>   Gnome 3.6 (w/ gnome-bluetooth).
>
> (this step may not do anything useful) Turn `Bluetooth` on Android off
>   and disconnect your USB/Bluetooth Adapter from your Linux machine (or
>   if you have an in built one, reset it using hcitool devname reset)
>
> Connect/turn on your `bluetooth` adapter on Linux. Ensure your adapter
>   is visible (can be set in gnome-bluetooth -- you should see a
>   `bluetooth` system tray icon).
>
> Turn on `bluetooth` on your Android device. Use Android to pair to the
>   adapter (I was unable to pair the other way around from Linux). A
>   dialog will come up asking you for a key. Put in any PIN you want.
>   Gnome should pop up a notification asking you for a key; put in the
>   same PIN you entered earlier. Your Android device and the key should
>   be paired at this point.

In Linux, open up a terminal and check what `bluetooth` services are available by typing in

```
sdptool browse local
```

If you already have a serial port service, make a note of what channel it is. If you don't, you can add the service:

```
sdptool add --channel=22 SP
```

Now listen on this channel using `rfcomm`:

```
sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 22
```

`rfcomm` will block, listening for a connection with a message like:

```
Waiting for connection on channel 22
```

Back on Android, I used the BlueTerm application (http://pymasde.es/blueterm/, also available freely on the google play store) though any similar application should work. Open up BlueTerm, go to options > Connect Device: select the paired adapter.

Hopefully, the application was able to connect. You'll see additional verification in the terminal where you blocked listening with a message like:

```
Waiting for connection on channel 22
Connection from 22:22:22:22:22:22 to /dev/rfcomm0
Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

Anything you type into the BlueTerm app should be going to `/dev/rfcomm0`. You can see stuff show up as you type by opening up a new terminal and doing something like:

```
cat /dev/rfcomm0
```

Source:
[How do I connect and send data to a bluetooth serial port on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux)

---

I would like to discuss the packaging of **bluez** and **bluez-utils**, since the move to **Bluez 5** has broken various commandline utilities, such as `sdptool`. For example (same as in this question),

```
$ sdptool browse local
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory
```

This is because Bluez 5 deprecated the old C interface which communicates over the socket /var/run/sdp, and this socket no longer exists. The help message from bluetoothd gives the solution:

```
$ /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --help
```

...

```
 -C, --compat                Provide deprecated command line interfaces
```

I apply this as follows

```
# nano /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service
```

like:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat
```

---

From muru's comment: On the above editing↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

Use `systemctl edit dbus-org.bluez.service` to create an override file which won't be lost on package update, instead of editing the service file directly.

---

then:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Needless to say, this edit is reverted every time bluez is updated. Now /var/run/sdp exists, but sdptool is still broken:

```
$ sdptool browse local
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: Permission denied
```

Comparing to Ubuntu (14.04 is still using Bluez 4) we see that the permissions on `/var/run/sdp` are different, and setting them to

```
# chmod 777 /var/run/sdp
```

(not persistent) finally makes `sdptool` work.

Source:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201672

Comment: Use `systemctl edit dbus-org.bluez.service` to create an override file which won't be lost on package update, instead of editing the service file directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, although a socket was created and bound on your side, it could not perform a successful call to connect(). (from `bluez-X-Y.Z/tools/rfcomm.c` source). A connect() call that fails (i.e. returns a value <0) can be caused by a lot of reasons.

*I guess your real question is "how can I get a successful connection?"*

To solve this issue, you must first be absolutely sure you have a listening socket on the other machine. I suggest you do it with another bluez stack running on a computer.

On the other machine run:

```
rfcomm listen 0           # listens on channel 1 by default
```

and on the test machine run:

```
rfcomm connect 0 00:11:22:33:44:55 1
```

the expected behavior is having no error.

Then you can use this mechanism to connect sockets and login, transfer file, etc... but that goes beyond your question.